# How do I change the default url "/posts/" routing in a Hugo site?

Tags: go, url, hugo, static-site, jamstack

I have created a new Hugo project. By default the urls route to `mysite.com/posts/my-first-post`. However I'm deploying to an existing domain where the url path for the posts is `mysite.com/blog/my-first-post`. How can I configure Hugo to go to /blog instead of /posts when view individual blog posts?

I've tried adding:

```
[permalinks]
    post = "/blog/:slug"
```

To my **config.toml** file and then running `hugo server --disableFastRender` so it looks for changes and restarted server but I haven't been able to change the url structure. How might I go about doing this? Currently running [anake](https://themes.gohugo.io/gohugo-theme-ananke/) theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoulda been `posts` instead of `post`.

**config.toml**

```
baseURL = "https://connorleech.info/"
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "Connor Leech"
theme = "ananke"
[permalinks]
  posts = "blog/:title"
```

Comment: still not working for me

Comment: `languageCode: "en-us"
title: "mysite"
uglyURLs: true
pygmentsstyle: 'monokai'
metaDataFormat: yaml
permalinks:
  posts: "/:title/"
markup:
  goldmark:
    renderer:
      unsafe: true`
i just want to remove the `/post/` in the url